# XSLT + Creating table structure

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to create a table structure that separates the header row by **THEAD** and the data rows by **TBODY**:

**Input XML:**

```
<Rowsets>
  <Rowset>
    <Columns>
      <Column Description="Date"/>
      <Column Description="Time"/>
    </Columns>
    <Row>
      <Date>DATA1</Date>
      <Time>DATA2</Time>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Date>DATA1</Date>
      <Time>DATA2</Time>
  </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

**The following XSLT does separates the header and body but I can't figure out how to wrap the  tags between the data rows:**

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <HTML>
    <BODY>
      <TABLE>
        <XSL:apply-templates/>
      </TABLE>
    </BODY>
  </HTML>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Columns|Row">
  <tr><xsl:apply-templates/></tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Columns">
  <thead><xsl:apply-templates/></thead>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Columns/*">
  <th><xsl:apply-templates select="@Description"/></th>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Row/*">
  <td><xsl:apply-templates/></td>
</xsl:template>
```

**Current HTML Output:**

```
  <THEAD>
    <TR>
      <TH>Date</TH><TH>Time</TH>
    </TR>
  </THEAD>
    <TR>
      <TD>DATA1</TD><TD>DATA2</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>DATA1</TD><TD>DATA2</TD>
    </TR>
```

How can I wrap the data rows with **TBODY**? Thanks!

Comment: Your template that matches `"Columns|Row"` will never apply to a `"Columns"` element, because your template that matches only `"Columns"` has a higher default priority (being more specific). So you might as well change `match="Columns|Row"` to `match="Row"` to make it less confusing to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably to add the following template to your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="Rowset">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Columns"/>
    <tbody>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Row"/>
    </tbody>
</xsl:template>
```

Complete stylesheet (with a couple other minor changes):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <HTML>
            <BODY>
                <TABLE>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </TABLE>
            </BODY>
        </HTML>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Rowset">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Columns"/>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Row"/>
        </tbody>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Columns">
        <thead><tr><xsl:apply-templates/></tr></thead>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Columns/*">
        <th><xsl:apply-templates select="@Description"/></th>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Row">
        <tr><xsl:apply-templates/></tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Row/*">
        <td><xsl:apply-templates/></td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can restrict (select) what nodes shall be applyed by `apply-templates`.
I'd use something like this:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <HTML>
    <BODY>
      <TABLE>
        <THEAD>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Columns"/>
        </THEAD>
        <TBODY>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Row"/>
        </TBODY>
      </TABLE>
    </BODY>
  </HTML>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Columns|Row">
  <TR><xsl:apply-templates/></TR>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Columns/*">
  <TH><xsl:value-of select="@Description"/></TH>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Row/*">
  <TD><xsl:apply-templates/></TD>
</xsl:template>
```