# XSLT + replace string with image in selected column

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to replace the different status indicators (e.g. Y or N) of a column "Status_Ind" with images. I would like to create "traffic lights" where:

- "Completed" is replaced with /img/green.jpg

- "In Progress" is replaced with /img/yellow.jpg

**Input XML:**

```
<Rowsets>
  <Rowset>
    <Columns>
      <Column Description="Status_Ind"/>
      <Column Description="Name"/>
    </Columns>
    <Row>
      <Status_Ind>Completed</Status_Ind>
      <Name>TASK1</Name>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Status_Ind>In Progress</Status_Ind>
      <Name>TASK2</Name>
    </Row>
  </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

For the XSLT, I am using the code in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8841189/1130511

**My attempt:**

```
<xsl:template match="@Description='Status_Ind']">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="Completed">
      <img src="../img/green.jpg" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="In Progress">
      <img src="../img/yellow.jpg" />
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy with two dedicated templates:

```
<xsl:template match="Status_Ind[. = 'Completed']">
  <img src="../img/green.jpg" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Status_Ind[. = 'In Progress']">
  <img src="../img/yellow.jpg" />
</xsl:template>
```

This way you could simply do

```
<xsl:template match="Row">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="Status_Ind" /></td>
    <!-- etc -->
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```